# How to switch ListView choice mode from single to multiple on Clicking event in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

i want to know how can i switch list view choice mode from single to multiple on button click.
so that i can select multiple list item and delete it and after deleting i should back to single choice mode.
if you have any idea how to implement this help me.
Thanks.

Comment: set setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE)

Comment: but this is not switching list view mode at runtime

Comment: i want to switch mode at runtime

Answer (score 2):

Implement `OnClick` functionality of the `button` and check the `ListView`'s status mode and change based on your preference as below....

```
   public void onClick(View v) {

   switch(v.getId()){
      case (R.id.mybutton):       
         ListView listView = getListView();
           if (listView.getChoiceMode() == ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE)
            {
               listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            }
            else if (listView.getChoiceMode() == ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE)
             {
              listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
             }
            break;
         }
       }
```

Comment: this is great for when you need the CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL but on older APIs such as Gingerbread too! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following code for that:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
     >
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `setChoiceMode` is not enough to display `checkboxes` beside your list rows. If you are using a basic layout for the rows, try `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice`. Else, you will have to add a checkbox to your row layout & manage its on/off state yourself in the adapter's `getView` method.