# How to switch from multiple to single ListView mode?

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to create a very basic to do list. I am a beginner and I am not able to convert single list view to multiple selection ListView. I have tried googling and I am not able to make it work.
When there is a long press on a entry, it will open a dialogue box to edit entry. For this I have made single selection listview.
On the top of app, there is delete button through which I intend to covert single selection to multiple. Nothing is happening after clicking this button.

I also tried checking answers from
[How to switch ListView choice mode from single to multiple on Clicking event in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083422/how-to-switch-listview-choice-mode-from-single-to-multiple-on-clicking-event-in).
None of the answers above worked!

```
private ArrayList<String> items;
private ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter;
private ListView lvItems;
Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
    items = new ArrayList<String>();
    itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
    lvItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
    lvItems.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    items.add("First item");
    items.add("Second Item");

    lvItems.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            //Try to add edit dialog here
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setTitle("Edit your entry");
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
            Button saveEntry = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button);
            final EditText editText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            editText.setText(items.get(position));
            dialog.show();

            saveEntry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String newText = editText.getText().toString();
                    items.set(position, newText);
                    itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            return true;
        }
    });

    //I want single ListView to change to multipe
    Button deleteButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);
    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (lvItems.getChoiceMode() == ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE){
                lvItems.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);




            }
        }
    });
}

public void onAddItem(View v){
    EditText etNewItem = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNewItem);
    String itemText = etNewItem.getText().toString();
    items.add(itemText);
    etNewItem.setText("");
}
```

}

Comment: I have not tried something similar to this yet, but a simple and easiest way to do this would be having two list views one with single selection & another one for multi selection (but sharing a common data source to feed the list items) and then make the visibility gone and visible based on the button selection. I know this is not most elegant solution but still this will work in this case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Move to recycler view. List view is outdated now.